# Sample n items without replacement in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following Prolog code which samples n items from a list without replacement:

```
samp(0,_,Sample,Sample).
samp(N,Domain0, Sample0, Sample):-
  N >= 0,              
  length(Domain0,L),
  RandomNumber is random(L),
  nth0(RandomNumber, Domain0, X),
  delete(Domain0,X,Domain1),
  append(Sample0,[X],Sample1),
  N1 is N-1,
  samp(N1,Domain1,Sample1,Sample).

sample(Domain,N,Sample):-
  samp(N,Domain,[],Sample).
```

Is there a 'nicer' way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, thanks for understanding exactly what this site is about. As a thank you, I just helped making sure that you got the Association Bonus in the Stack Exchange network. Welcome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog you could do this that way:

```
sample_swi(Domain, N, Sample) :-
    random_permutation(Domain, Permutation),
    length(Sample, N),
    append(Sample, _, Permutation).
```

Be careful, this predicate is not a true relation (just as in your code).

Comment: What is the definition of a true relation?

Comment: @S0rin prolog predicates are not functions - they should represent relations. Above code is a function: it works only "one-way". You can query for `sample_swi([1,2], 1, Sample)` but you'll get error for `sample_swi(X, 1, [1]).`. If it was "true" relation then it would work both ways and it would work even for this query: `sample_swi(X, Y, Z)`. This is important in Prolog.